# Ship extra files in kernel module recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

Is there a way I can ship more files when building an out of tree kernel module?

I have tried something like this:

```
FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}/my_program"
do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${D}/my_program ${D}${bindir}/my_program
}
```

And like this:

```
FILES_kernel-module-${PN} += "${bindir}/my_program"
do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${D}/my_program ${D}${bindir}/my_program
}
```

But still complains:

```
ERROR: QA Issue: my-module: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr
  /usr/bin
  /usr/bin/my_program
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
my-module: 3 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite common situation - you have installed additional binary but it hasn't been added to output package (*installed but not shipped*).

Solution should be based on type of file that you need to add to output image.

Check this thread: [2 step solution to ERROR: QA Issue: Files/directories were  installed but not shipped](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2016-January/028127.html)

Also if you need to quickly verify if the files were properly build etc., you can just add this line in your build/local.conf (as you have already installed them):

> IMAGE_INSTALL += "{binary_name}"

Edit:

In addition to below comment from OP:
Sorry for my misunderstanding, it looks that you need to inherit *module.bbclass* in your recipe, check out the doc: [Yocto Mega Manual - module.bbclass](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-module) and let me know if this suits you.
You can also check this simple tutorial: [Howto build a kernel module out of the kernel tree](http://wiki.kaeilos.com/index.php/Howto_build_a_kernel_module_out_of_the_kernel_tree)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that solution won't work for a kernel module (when you add `include module` to your recipe). That solution is basically what I was trying to do until now.

Answer (score 2):

FILES_${PN} can't be used for kernel recipes, since for the kernel at least by default ${PN} does not appear in PACKAGES. "kernel-module-${PN}" isn't valid either. I'm guessing you'd want to add the file to the kernel-base package like so:

`FILES_kernel-base += "${bindir}/my_program"`

Comment: I think at this point we need to see your entire recipe before we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that module.bbclass removes ${PN} from PACKAGES but it does clear FILES_${PN}. So if you want to add any files to your package, you must set FILES_${PN} **after** inheriting module.